# KendoUI Grid errors in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, telerik, kendo-ui

Im receiving a weird error that is only occurring in my web application in internet explorer (v9.0.8). It occurs when I try to instantiate a grid more than once on a div.

(I know this is a weird situation but Im doing it for a reason and it is easier to simplify the problem by just saying the error occurs when setting up the grid more than once)

I have recreated the problem in jfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gwHkv/25/). You will see that the grid loads up fine to start with. But when you click the "Click me" button the grid is setup again and if you check the console window it has an error saying "SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object 
kendo.all.min.js, line 8 character 73742".

It has something to do with the datasource because if you try this [version](http://jsfiddle.net/gwHkv/26/) where I have removed the datasource from the grid it no longer errors.

Can anyone provide any guidance on why this error is occurring?

Thanks

More Information..
The reason that I perform this task is because it is a single page application. So as I move to another page I am dynamically paging the content on the screen. When I return back to the listing page I must call the setup listing to refresh the grid. I have added another jfiddle to show this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gwHkv/30/). When you click on the "Click Here to Refresh HTML" it resets the html in the div and than sets up the grid. If you look in IE's console you see a  SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8) error.

Comment: Honestly, I think this should be asked at Kendo forums... This looks like an error on the Kendo developers part. BTW, your first fiddle produces a script error in IE8 right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

So I can only guess why you receive this error without looking at the source code, however you can easily bypass this issue by removing the grid before re-inserting it. I used the jQuery remove method on the #grid selector inside your `TestRefreshHtml()` method and everything worked just fine.

```
function TestRefreshHtml()
{
    alert('in refresh');

    //Remove the grid before initializing a new one
    $('#grid').remove();

 $('#content').html('<div id="grid"/><button id="buttonClickTest">Click Me</Button><button id="buttonClickTest2">Click Me To Refresh HTML</Button>');

SetupGrid();
}
```

I think this issue might be related to using an id multiple times, but I'm not positive. 
I tested this fix in your second fiddle and the grid loaded fine in IE with no errors.